# Define a property on an object that is both a value accessor and a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is an API (`d3.map` to be specific), which implements a method `size`. However I would like to extend it so that it remains backwards compatible, but it can also be used as a value accessor/getter (because that is how it's specified in `ES6` now):

```
var map = d3.map();
map.set(0, 1);
console.log(map.size()); // Old code, should still work
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(map.size)); // Should also work (as a getter)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are no way to do what you like. 
The only way out is replace `size()` with `getSize()`

```
class Map{
    public get size(){
        return 1;
    }

    public set size(size:number){

    }

    getSize():number{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

### Update

There is one solution. Just use key length for new features, and use key size for backward compatibility. It would be looks like a C# `List` class.

```
class Map {
    private count = 0;


    public get length(): number {
        return this.count;
    }

    public set length(length: number) {
        this.count = length;
    }

    public size(): number;
    public size(size: number): void;
    public size(size?: number): any {
        if (size) {
            this.count = size;
        } else {
            return this.count;
        }
    }

}
```

Your example

```
var map = d3.map();
map.set(0, 1);
console.log(map.size()); // Old code, should still work
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(map.length)); // Should also work (as a getter)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my friend, there are no way... Just looks to JS Object core - it's just a dictionary where string is key and value is object. Now imagine that you the ``size`` key should return the function and the primitive object like number in the same time... Yep, it is impossible. Also the number is just a primitive object, and it can`t work like function, because ``Function`` it is another hierarchy node, and it is not CrossRef with Number class.

Comment: But, there is one good solution for you, just use key ``length`` for new features, and use key ``size`` for backward compatibility, looks for update in my post